# Prime numbers program:I want to know to know reason for my successful program

Tags: python

I am a student who just started learning python.I was making a program to print prime numbers from 1 till 300 using break and continue and it executed perfectly but I am not getting one thing why it is not printing 1 .How range function works if the given range is  (a,a).You can understand why I am asking that after seeing my code because I think this is the reason it didn't print 1 in the prime numbers program.

```
a=range(1,301)
for num in a:
   for d in range(2,num+1)
           rem=num % d
           if(rem==0):
                if (d != num ):
                     break
            if (num != d):
                 continue
            print (num, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your code for

```
a=range(1,301) # this gives numbers from  1 to 300
for num in a: #assume we are at num =1
   for d in range(2,num+1) # in this range fnc we start from 2 till 2 so this loop is not even executed
           rem=num % d
           if(rem==0):
                if (d != num ):
                     break
            if (num != d):
                 continue
            print (num, end=' ')
```

```
a=range(1,301)
for num in a:
    if num ==1: print (num, end=' ') # 1 is a co prime
    for d in range(2,num+1):
        rem=num % d
        if(rem==0):
            if (d != num ):
                break
        if (num != d):
            continue
        print (num, end=' ')
```

range function for (a,b) goes from a to b i.e. start from a to the doorstep of b (so b is not included)

if you are already at b for (a,b) where a==b then range function does not start

Comment: I see .I thought it would return me range in backward form from 2 till 1 when my number is 1.so range function with two arguments will work when the values are in ascending order.?? Thank you so much for answering me.

Comment: if you want it backwards you have to specify a negative step eg `range(10,1,-1)` so this will give 10 9 8...2!(starting from 10 to 1) By default, it's 1(+ive) and will email so until you specify otherwise

Comment: okay.I barely use this site so don't know how things work here. ^-^